# iOS4 location tracking in the background and with a time interval

Tags: iphone, objective-c, gps, multitasking

In iOS4, it possible to do an accurate GPS location update with a preset interval while my app is in the background? If so, how?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm going to set the interval to about 30 - 45 minutes so that it doesn't eat up battery life.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400628/ios-multi-tasking-track-gps-location

Comment: Is there a specific answer on using a time interval to activate location tracking while in the background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, setting a time interval is not possible. You can just opt in for location updates in the background – either less precise using cell tower triangulation and WiFi hotspots or more precise involving the GPS. Everything else is up to the OS.

Comment: I've seen background GPS time interval settings in apps like Loopt. How did they do it?

Comment: I've seen apps that can trigger the phone to update location from a remote server. Any idea how that is done?

Comment: What apps are you referring to? It's not possible to activate an app from a remote server if that app is in the background.

Comment: There's an app called Device Locator (http://device-locator.com/) that let's the user trigger "Emergency Mode" from a web interface to track the device, even if the app is in the background or 'terminated'. And then there's the Apple's Find My iPhone app. What do you think?

Answer (score 3):

[iOS Multi-Tasking Track GPS Location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400628/ios-multi-tasking-track-gps-location)

This may help some.

Comment: Thanks, I was reading the official guide chapter on executing code in the background. What is the difference between that and general multitasking? I ask because I saw this in the chapter: 

"Important: Most application developers do not need to read this chapter. This chapter does not address the basic multitasking support that all applications should adopt. It addresses only the steps needed to support executing code while the application is in the background state. For information about how to support basic multitasking in your applications, see “Multitasking.”"